# Apend Athentication token to the Alamorefire URL request

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I'm new to swift and working on a project in swift 3.0. I managed to setup an alamorefire class to call the webservises and its working fine. the code as bellow.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class APIManager: NSObject {
    class func apiGet(serviceName:String,parameters: [String:Any]?, completionHandler: @escaping (JSON?, NSError?) -> ()) {

        Alamofire.request(serviceName, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                if let data = response.result.value{
                    let json = JSON(data)
                    completionHandler(json,nil)
                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                completionHandler(nil,response.result.error as NSError?)
                break

            }
        }
    }
```

Also when ever I wants to call the method I do as follow in the respective viewcontroller class.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {
let appURLs = AppURLs.sharedInstance

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let params = [
            "userName":"abc",
            "password":"abc"
        ]
        let loginURL = (self.appURLs.mainBaseURL)+(self.appURLs.addToSaveURL)

        APIManager.apiPost(serviceName: loginURL, parameters: params) { (json:JSON?, error:NSError?) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                return
            }
            print(json!)
        }
    }
```

But since I have created a separate class to retrieve the authentication token, my goal is to append the authentication token method along with the method show above (apiPost method). The code of the class that I've created to retrieve the authentication token as bellow. Any help would much appreciate.

```
import Foundation

class ServerRequests {

    let parameters: String?
    let serverURL: String?

    init(parameters: String, serverURL: String) {
        self.parameters = parameters
        self.serverURL = serverURL
    }

    init(serverURL: String) {
        self.parameters = nil
        self.serverURL = serverURL
    }

    func connectToServer() -> NSMutableURLRequest {
        let post:NSString = parameters! as NSString
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: serverURL!)!
        let postData:NSData = post.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)! as NSData
        let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length ) as NSString
        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = postData as Data
        request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        request.setValue(prefs.value(forKey: "TOKEN")! as? String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Cvs-Token")
        return request
    }
```

Comment: i dont see in your where you retrieve the token from the server

Comment: Lets say that I have saved it to User defaults and Im retrieving it in the "connectToServer" method

Comment: since you rejected my edit: with your previous comment this line `The code of the class that I've created to retrieve the authentication token as bellow` should be `The code of the class that I've created to retrieve WITH the authentication token as bellow` otherwise it means you retrieve the authentication token with this class. `bellow` means shouting and not `below`.

Comment: caan u update the code sir

Comment: correct code should be posted as answers below your question. an edit is only to improve your question and fix typos, but edit is not to fix your code